# force tinymce to enter newline with enter keypress rather than making a new paragraph

Tags: jquery, tinymce, keypress, line-breaks, paragraph

When a user hits the Enter key while using TinyMCE, it doesn't add a new line, it adds a new paragraph. Can I change this behavior and force it only to add a line break `<br />` instead of a new paragraph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops the answer's right [here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:forced_root_block): https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    forced_root_block : 'p'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In TinyMCE 6.1+, there's new option. The previous option was obsoleted.

```js
newline_behavior: 'block',
```

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/content-behavior-options/#newline_behavior
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/6.1-release-notes/#new-newline_behavior-option-controls-what-happens-when-the-return-or-enter-key-is-pressed-or-the-mceinsertnewline-command-is-used

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to change the defaults, then in the editor just press shift and enter together and it will take you to a new line